# jqGrid—setGridWidth function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to call jqGrid's setGridWidth function, but I'm getting the error:

> Object [object Object] has no method 'setGridWidth'

I'm sure this is something stupid.  Here's the code to display the grid (which is fine) and then try to resize it.

```
    $("#jqGridElement").jqGrid({
        datastr: tableSrc,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
        datatype: "jsonstring",
        colNames: ['title', 'subtitle'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'title', index: 'title', width: 55 },
            { name: 'subtitle', index: 'subtitle'}],
        height: 'auto',

        gridview: true
    });

    $("#jqGridElement").setGridWidth(600);'
```

**EDIT**

I've also tried:

```
var gridObj = $("#jqGridElement").jqGrid({  datastr: tableSrc, .......
gridObj.setGridWidth(300);
```

Same result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose that you set `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;` like I did in my last demos.

The "standard" (legacy API) code of jqGrid set many method extensions of jQuery. It's dangerous in case of usage many other jQuery Plugins. The probability to have name conflicts are increased. So it's recommended to use "new style" jqGrid API. In case of `setGridWidth` method you should use

```
$("#jqGridElement").jqGrid('setGridWidth', 600);
```

instead of

```
$("#jqGridElement").setGridWidth(600);
```

One small general remark: I recommend you to define `gridObj` as

```
var gridObj = $("#jqGridElement");
gridObj.jqGrid({  datastr: tableSrc,...
```

instead of

```
var gridObj = $("#jqGridElement").jqGrid({  datastr: tableSrc,...
```

The advantage is that the value of `gridObj` will be set before the call of `$("#jqGridElement").jqGrid` and you can use safe `gridObj` inside of any `jqGrid` event. For example you can use `gridObj` variable inside of `loadComplete` event. In case of usage in the way like you use it now the `gridObj` variable can be `undefined` at the first usage of `loadComplete` event.

Comment: Your assumption was spot on.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you'd like to go for a hat trick :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260786/jqgridreloading-data

Comment: And I really liked your advice about using gridObj.  Thanks again again.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: You are welcome! I will look the referenced question shortly.